# Fastest way to update price from another database

Tags: magento2

We just migrated our magento store from 1.9 to 2.4 version, but in the process not all the prices have been imported correctly. We have a relatively huge database (more than 2.5M product, its a bookstore). Of course I can do it by running a simple sql query, but I was wondering if there's a fastest way to accomplish this task.

Thanks

Comment: You won't find a _faster_ way in terms of execution speed, however, much more failure-safe ones would be for example utilizing Magento's APIs or a simple CSV import.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking safest way, use magento default `Export/Import` functionality.